# UIMA Regex annotator

Tags: uima

Am new to UIMA architecture. I downloaded UIMA SDK (http://uima.apache.org/downloads.cgi#Latest Official Releases) and also corresponding Eclipse plugins. Am able to run the tutorial examples successfully.

I took Regex Annotator code from apache SVN (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/uima/sandbox/trunk/RegularExpressionAnnotator/?pathrev=627314) and am trying to run the RegEx Annotator but I always get org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: Annotator class "org.apache.uima.annotator.regex.impl.RegExAnnotator" was not found.

All files are in place, I have set UIMA_HOME to required directory, I have uima-core.jar and xbean-1.03.jar in my build path.

When I check the bin directory and de-compile those classes, am able to see the RegExAnnotator.class as well.

Can someone figure out what am I missing and how to re-solve this? I did quite an amount of google, I saw a similar post in another website but no solution. Am kind of stuck here. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you could use UIMA Ruta workbench.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem. All I did was in my Run Configurations I pointed to RegularExpression related project that I created. By default it points to uima-examples project.